# Piped unix command not executing in java Program

Tags: java, ps

I am trying to get the memory usage for a particular Process using its pid in a java program
using the following command 
ps -eo pid,pmem,comm | grep java | awk '{print ($2)}'

While this command works on unix terminal, it does not work in java  I keep on getting null result even when I run another java program (to populate the ps table with java processes).

```
String[] PipedCommand = {
                        "/bin/bash",
                        "-c",
                        "ps -eo pid,pmem,comm | grep java | awk '{print ($2)}'"
            };
            Process command1=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(PipedCommand);
            command1.waitFor(); 
            BufferedReader reader1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(command.getInputStream())); 
            String line1=reader1.readLine();
            if(line1 != null)
            {
                System.out.println(" Memory percentage is "+line1);
            }
```

I would appreciate if someone could tell me if there is something wrong with the approach

Comment: You should not assume that the first line will contain the number you want; try this: `ps -eo pid,pmem,comm | grep sh | awk '{print ($2)}'` -- I get nine results. You cannot assume that you will get exactly one `java` process on the machine. `ps -C java` would be better than including `grep(1)` in the command, but still might return hundreds or thousands of processes.

Comment: I agree with whatever you say, actually I am passing the pid of a process using pgrep to the grep command given in PipedCommand and running this PipedCommand on all the obtained pid's.

Comment: It would probably be easier to debug the _actual_ code you have trouble with...

Comment: You should also ***not*** assume that `$PATH` will have any particular value.  Specify absolute paths to all executables and files.